# Как заполнить dataframe для работы с другими функциями python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Возвращает пустой фрейм

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
    data = await client.Data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_new = df

    await client.close_connection()

def result():
    print(df_new)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    result()
```

Comment: Ну напишите `global df_new` в начале функции `main`, хотя лучше возвращать данные из функции в явном виде. И собирать результат через `async.gather` или ещё как-то так. Сейчас у вас формируется локальная переменная `df_new`, не имеющая ничего общего с глобальной переменной.

Comment: **df**.DataFrame() - опечатка

Comment: global df_new

df_new = df

внутри main помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

async def main():
    global df_new
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
    data = await client.Data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_new = df

    await client.close_connection()

def result():
    print(df_new)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    result()
```

```
async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
    data = await client.Data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    await client.close_connection()
    return df

def result(df_new):
    print(df_new)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    df_new = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    result(df_new)
```